# The search application 'Search Service Application' on server did not finish loading. View the event logs on the affected server for more information

Tags: 2013, search, installation, configuration, update

we have applied some windows 2008 r2 security updates + SP 2013 security updates, to our SharePoint server 2013. but some updates failed . Now i checked the SP logs and i found these errors:-

```
10/22/2015 00:37:11.58  hostcontrollerservice.exe (0x0334)          0x081C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjm9   Unexpected  SPReaderWriterLock named [SPInitializeOnceLock] waited 172 milliseconds to acquire lock. Call stack: (enable Verbose for stack trace)    
10/22/2015 00:37:11.58  SPUCHostService.exe (0x0878)                0x091C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjm9   Unexpected  SPReaderWriterLock named [SPInitializeOnceLock] waited 172 milliseconds to acquire lock. Call stack: (enable Verbose for stack trace)    
10/22/2015 00:37:11.59  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0850)                       0x0860  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjm9   Unexpected  SPReaderWriterLock named [SPInitializeOnceLock] waited 172 milliseconds to acquire lock. Call stack: (enable Verbose for stack trace)    
10/22/2015 00:37:12.06  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0850)                       0x0860  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  SPReaderWriterLock named [SPInitializeOnceLock] held for 406 milliseconds. Call stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPReaderWriterLock.SPReaderWriterLockScope.Dispose()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Local()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServer.get_Local()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPServerPerformanceInspector.GetLocalWebApplications()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPServerPerformanceInspector..ctor()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPServerPerformanceInspector..cctor()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerStore.InitializeTimer(Int64& cacheVersion, Object& jobDefinitions, Int32& timerMode, Guid& se...  
10/22/2015 00:37:12.06* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0850)                       0x0860  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  ...rverId, Boolean& isServerBusy)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPNativeConfigurationProvider.InitializeTimer(Int64& cacheVersion, Object& jobDefinitions, Int32& timerMode, Guid& serverId, Boolean& isServerBusy)     
10/22/2015 00:37:12.08  SPUCHostService.exe (0x0878)                0x091C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  SPReaderWriterLock named [SPInitializeOnceLock] held for 421 milliseconds. Call stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPReaderWriterLock.SPReaderWriterLockScope.Dispose()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Local()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_Local()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.InitializeFarmVerification()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeInitializer.Initialize()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.InitializeInternal(ISPUserCodePoolableProcessFactory processFactory)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHostService.InitializeThreadProc(Object s...  
10/22/2015 00:37:12.08* SPUCHostService.exe (0x0878)                0x091C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  ...tateInfo)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()       
10/22/2015 00:37:12.08  hostcontrollerservice.exe (0x0334)          0x081C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  SPReaderWriterLock named [SPInitializeOnceLock] held for 406 milliseconds. Call stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPReaderWriterLock.SPReaderWriterLockScope.Dispose()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Local()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchService.GetService(SPFarm farm)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchService.get_Service()     at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchVssWriter.SearchVssWriterInterop.CreateWriter()     at Microsoft.Ceres.HostController.Service.ServiceRunner.OnStart(String[] args)     at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)     at System.Threading.ExecutionConte...  
10/22/2015 00:37:12.08* hostcontrollerservice.exe (0x0334)          0x081C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  ...xt.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()       
10/22/2015 00:37:13.84  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0850)                       0x0860  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  SPReaderWriterLock named [Process Context Lock] held for 562 milliseconds. Call stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPReaderWriterLock.SPReaderWriterLockScope.Dispose()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPProcessContext.Get[T]()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Farm()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServer.get_Local()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPServerPerformanceInspector.GetLocalWebApplications()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPServerPerformanceInspector..ctor()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPServerPerformanceInspector..cctor()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerStore.InitializeTimer(Int64& cacheVersio...  
10/22/2015 00:37:13.84* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0850)                       0x0860  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  ...n, Object& jobDefinitions, Int32& timerMode, Guid& serverId, Boolean& isServerBusy)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPNativeConfigurationProvider.InitializeTimer(Int64& cacheVersion, Object& jobDefinitions, Int32& timerMode, Guid& serverId, Boolean& isServerBusy)    
10/22/2015 00:37:13.84  SPUCHostService.exe (0x0878)                0x091C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  SPReaderWriterLock named [Process Context Lock] held for 577 milliseconds. Call stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPReaderWriterLock.SPReaderWriterLockScope.Dispose()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPProcessContext.Get[T]()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Farm()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_Local()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.InitializeFarmVerification()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeInitializer.Initialize()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.InitializeInternal(ISPUserCodePoolableProcessFactory processFactory)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserC...  
10/22/2015 00:37:13.84* SPUCHostService.exe (0x0878)                0x091C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  ...odeExecutionHostService.InitializeThreadProc(Object stateInfo)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()      
10/22/2015 00:37:13.84  hostcontrollerservice.exe (0x0334)          0x081C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  SPReaderWriterLock named [Process Context Lock] held for 592 milliseconds. Call stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPReaderWriterLock.SPReaderWriterLockScope.Dispose()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPProcessContext.Get[T]()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Farm()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchService.GetService(SPFarm farm)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchService.get_Service()     at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchVssWriter.SearchVssWriterInterop.CreateWriter()     at Microsoft.Ceres.HostController.Service.ServiceRunner.OnStart(String[] args)     at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback...  
10/22/2015 00:37:13.84* hostcontrollerservice.exe (0x0334)          0x081C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  ...(Object state)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()      
10/22/2015 00:37:13.93  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0850)                       0x0860  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  SPReaderWriterLock named [Process Context Lock] held for 687 milliseconds. Call stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPReaderWriterLock.SPReaderWriterLockScope.Dispose()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPProcessContext.Get[T]()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Farm()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServer.get_Local()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPServerPerformanceInspector.GetLocalWebApplications()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPServerPerformanceInspector..ctor()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPServerPerformanceInspector..cctor()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerStore.InitializeTimer(Int64& cacheVersio...  
10/22/2015 00:37:13.93* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0850)                       0x0860  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  ...n, Object& jobDefinitions, Int32& timerMode, Guid& serverId, Boolean& isServerBusy)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPNativeConfigurationProvider.InitializeTimer(Int64& cacheVersion, Object& jobDefinitions, Int32& timerMode, Guid& serverId, Boolean& isServerBusy)    
10/22/2015 00:37:13.93  hostcontrollerservice.exe (0x0334)          0x081C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  SPReaderWriterLock named [Process Context Lock] held for 702 milliseconds. Call stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPReaderWriterLock.SPReaderWriterLockScope.Dispose()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPProcessContext.Get[T]()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Farm()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchService.GetService(SPFarm farm)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchService.get_Service()     at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchVssWriter.SearchVssWriterInterop.CreateWriter()     at Microsoft.Ceres.HostController.Service.ServiceRunner.OnStart(String[] args)     at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback...  
10/22/2015 00:37:13.93* hostcontrollerservice.exe (0x0334)          0x081C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  ...(Object state)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()      
10/22/2015 00:37:13.95  SPUCHostService.exe (0x0878)                0x091C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  SPReaderWriterLock named [Process Context Lock] held for 686 milliseconds. Call stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPReaderWriterLock.SPReaderWriterLockScope.Dispose()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPProcessContext.Get[T]()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Farm()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_Local()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.InitializeFarmVerification()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeInitializer.Initialize()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.InitializeInternal(ISPUserCodePoolableProcessFactory processFactory)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserC...  
10/22/2015 00:37:13.95* SPUCHostService.exe (0x0878)                0x091C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ahjnc   Unexpected  ...odeExecutionHostService.InitializeThreadProc(Object stateInfo)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()      
10/22/2015 00:33:42.72  NodeRunnerQuery1-9004fabc-2086- (0x17CC)    0x17D0  Search                          Search Platform Services        aiy4z   Unexpected  AssemblyReflector : Failed to load dependency assembly in load context and in load from context. Assembly: BihConsumerInterop System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.    
10/22/2015 00:33:42.72  NodeRunnerAdmin1-9004fabc-2086- (0x1588)    0x158C  Search                          Search Platform Services        aiy4z   Unexpected  AssemblyReflector : Failed to load dependency assembly in load context and in load from context. Assembly: BihConsumerInterop System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.    
10/22/2015 00:33:42.74  NodeRunnerAnalytics1-9004fabc-2 (0x16CC)    0x16D0  Search                          Search Platform Services        aiy4z   Unexpected  AssemblyReflector : Failed to load dependency assembly in load context and in load from context. Assembly: BihConsumerInterop System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.    
10/22/2015 00:33:42.79  NodeRunnerContent1-9004fabc-208 (0x16F4)    0x16F8  Search                          Search Platform Services        aiy4z   Unexpected  AssemblyReflector : Failed to load dependency assembly in load context and in load from context. Assembly: BihConsumerInterop System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.    
10/22/2015 00:33:43.54  NodeRunnerQuery1-9004fabc-2086- (0x17CC)    0x17D0  Search                          Search Platform Services        aiy4z   Unexpected  AssemblyReflector : Failed to load dependency assembly in load context and in load from context. Assembly: BihConsumerInterop System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.    
10/22/2015 00:33:43.55  NodeRunnerContent1-9004fabc-208 (0x16F4)    0x16F8  Search                          Search Platform Services        aiy4z   Unexpected  AssemblyReflector : Failed to load dependency assembly in load context and in load from context. Assembly: BihConsumerInterop System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.   


10/22/2015 02:00:01.37  wsstracing.exe (0x0864)                     0x13AC  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   
10/22/2015 02:00:01.37  wsstracing.exe (0x0864)                     0x13AC  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   
10/22/2015 02:00:01.37  wsstracing.exe (0x0864)                     0x13AC  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   
10/22/2015 02:00:01.37  wsstracing.exe (0x0864)                     0x13AC  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   
10/22/2015 02:00:01.37  wsstracing.exe (0x0864)                     0x13AC  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   
10/22/2015 02:00:01.82  w3wp.exe (0x27EC)                           0x2134  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: (none)     
10/22/2015 02:00:01.84  w3wp.exe (0x1BD0)                           0x0890                                  0xC33B01A                       ahjqp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 10/22/2015 02:00:01.24, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0839492170094244 for Data Source=***\SPS;Initial Catalog=Search_Service_Application_DB_980752b28a2c45a3a992efb90fcfe7d2;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15    c2f3399d-4c2b-c0b7-30fc-0a225b7c0f67
10/22/2015 02:00:01.84  w3wp.exe (0x1BD0)                           0x0890  SharePoint Foundation           Service Connections             ev2x    High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] System.ServiceModel Transfer: 0 :  c2f3399d-4c2b-c0b7-30fc-0a225b7c0f67
10/22/2015 02:00:01.84  w3wp.exe (0x1BD0)                           0x0890  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: (none)    c2f3399d-4c2b-c0b7-30fc-0a225b7c0f67
10/22/2015 02:00:01.85  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0850)                       0x1248  SharePoint Portal Server        Feed Cache                      7155    Warning     FeedCache last modified time repopulation failed, social experience will suffer if this happens many times in an hour.  UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have bdeb6d58-f138-4070-84af-f95d1d586617    c2f3399d-4c2b-c0b7-30fc-02eb6c15bce4
10/22/2015 02:00:01.85  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0850)                       0x1248  SharePoint Foundation           Timer                           6398    Critical    The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.LMTRepopulationJob (ID 92266f8f-17fd-4bd4-b2ff-2f32ba073abb) threw an exception. More information is included below.  UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have bdeb6d58-f138-4070-84af-f95d1d586617    c2f3399d-4c2b-c0b7-30fc-02eb6c15bce4
10/22/2015 02:00:01.85  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0850)                       0x1248  SharePoint Foundation           Timer                           72ae    Unexpected  Exception stack trace:    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_FeedCacheLMTTTLDeltaHours()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.LMTRepopulationJob.DoRepopulation(Boolean fullRepopulation, DateTime lastSuccessfullRunTime)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.LMTRepopulationJob.Execute()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxyJob.Execute(SPJobState jobState)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result)  c2f3399d-4c2b-c0b7-30fc-02eb6c15bce4
10/22/2015 02:00:01.92  w3wp.exe (0x1DBC)                           0x151C  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: (none)    c0fab6a6-3e1d-4c16-9113-781e0a412c0f
10/22/2015 02:00:02.09  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0850)                       0x25E0  SharePoint Foundation           Health                          2138    Warning     The SharePoint Health Analyzer detected a condition requiring your attention.  Drives are at risk of running out of free space.  Available drive space is less than five times the value of physical memory. This is dangerous because it does not provide enough room for a full memory dump with continued operation. It also could cause problems with the Virtual Memory swap file: System (*** - C:\).  Examine the failing servers and delete old logs or free space on the drives. For more information about this rule, see "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142688".    c2f3399d-7c24-c0b7-30fc-067f250a03f1
10/22/2015 02:00:02.12  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0850)                       0x0990  SharePoint Foundation           General                         84yi    Unexpected  An SPPerformanceCounter was not properly disposed.  This could cause excessive memory use.   
10/22/2015 02:00:03.12  wsstracing.exe (0x0864)                     0x13AC  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   
10/22/2015 02:00:03.12  wsstracing.exe (0x0864)                     0x13AC  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   
10/22/2015 02:00:03.12  wsstracing.exe (0x0864)                     0x13AC  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.
```

so seems the search service is raising errors , so i accessed the search service from the central administration, but i got this error :-

> ```
> The search application 'Search Service Application' on server did not finish loading. View the event logs on the affected server for more information.
> ```

[image]

so can anyone adivce what is causing this ? now the search itself is working well , where i can search our sites and i am getting results.. but i am unable to access the Content Sources and i will get this error:-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you run the PSconfig wizard after the SharePoint security patches? Could you please Run the Psconfig command-line tool for SharePoint Products as follows:

```
Psconfig -cmd secureresources
```

Also try to restart the search service.

Verify that no group policies have been set on the local user groups 'WSS_WPG' and 'WSS_ADMIN_WPG'.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2770732

Comment: but i am afraid of running the product configuration wizard , as some updates failed to be installed.. now from the logs i can see that there is exception regarding space such as "This is dangerous because it does not provide enough room for a full memory dump with continued operation.",, so could this be causing this problem ?

Comment: did you reboot the servers? also did you try to reinstall the updates which failed?

Comment: this what i will be doing,, but to avoid the same problem , i am trying to understand what caused the problem... is it realted to the DB being slow or almost full as mentioned on the logs ?

Comment: you cant blame to anything...becuase Patching having two steps...Bits installation and Configuration wizard....so i would just make sure, enough disk space and memory available on server.

Comment: now we have tried to install 73 updates in the patch , where 23 of them failed and 50 succeeded. and it took too long for the patch to complete around 6 hours.. so now is it risky if i run the product configuration wizard, where part of the 73 updates were not installed correctly ? or this does not matter ? second point . after working hours i will try to install the failed 23 updates again ,, so do u recommend to postpone running the product configuration wizard till i re-try installing the failed updates?

Comment: 1st i want to know what updates you are applying and which way....2nd failed updates are for SharePoint or for the OS?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when changing the Search DB names and trying to bring the Search service out of suspended state.

Resolution: Ensure that your Search Server Service and your Search Host Controller Service are using the same service account (Found in "Security > Configure Service Accounts")

Comment: This solved it for me in combination with an invalid service account password.

Answer (score 0):

consider if you are using SQl server Always ON and CliConfg aliases

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/172962/16880