# error while configure reporting services and run configuration wizard

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, configuration-wizard

I want to configure SQL Server reporting services service sharepoint 2013. install  sql server 2012 then install manually service pack 1. In During installation of service pack 1, Reporting Services Add-in for share point product Failed.
[image]
 I try to resolve according to this article

[Error 1603 Installing Reporting Services Add-In onto a New SharePoint Server](http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2014/12/error-1603-installing-reporting-services-add-in-onto-a-new-sharepoint-server/)

My problem is not resolved.
I read in this article ,should run configuration wizard but in the last step, Configuration Failed.
[image]

for resolved last error I find out this question

[SharePoint configuration wizard will raise Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118287/sharepoint-configuration-wizard-will-raise-microsoft-sharepoint-postsetupconfigu)

I do that and error is still there!!

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved!

1. Uninstall sql server reporting services service
2. according to this article [Products Configuration Wizard](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/products-configuration-wizard-failed/) I review logs form `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS` , I solved issue from server (issues can be different)
3. run configuration wizard successfully
4. Install reporting services service
5. create report library .....